# Progress bar in pyprind of Python

Tags: progress-bar, python-idle

**The following code I used in Python IDLE Shell 3.10.1 using pyprind**

```
 for i in pyprind.prog_bar(range(10)):
    time.sleep(0.2)

0% [#         ] 100% | ETA: 00:00:01
0% [##        ] 100% | ETA: 00:00:01
0% [###       ] 100% | ETA: 00:00:01
0% [####      ] 100% | ETA: 00:00:01
0% [#####     ] 100% | ETA: 00:00:01
0% [######    ] 100% | ETA: 00:00:00
0% [#######   ] 100% | ETA: 00:00:00
0% [########  ] 100% | ETA: 00:00:00
0% [######### ] 100% | ETA: 00:00:00
0% [##########] 100% | ETA: 00:00:00
0% [##########] 100% | ETA: 00:00:00
Total time elapsed: 00:00:02
```

I expected the output with a single progress bar. Why have I got this output. Please somebody help  how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and what you show, pyprind assumes that it is running inside an environment in which its output lines replace previous lines.  The IDLE Shell is not currently such an environment. Running your code in the system command-line terminal/console will probably get the behavior you want.

Note that IDLE is primarily meant for development of programs, not for routinely running them.  For development, seeing all of the output of a program, without anything being erased, can be an advantage.